# java static method why is needed

Tags: java, static-methods

I'm using eclipse as IDE for java. 
I wrote the following code, but I have one error on `loadStrade()`. Eclipse suggested me to change `loadStrade` from `public void` to `public static`, and I don't understand why?
I've  looked for similar problem and I've found some problems like mine, but I still not understand why I have to change method to static. Uffa!

In the code, routesNet is a graph (jgraphT), and loadStrade() is used to populate vertex and edge.
Can I have help. Thanks, Fabrizio

```
public class GestioneStrade {

private Stradario routesNet;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Instantiate Stradario and fill it with routes and cross
     * 
     */
    GestioneStrade m = new GestioneStrade(); //istance of gestionestrade ok?
    // now I set new routesNet
    m.setRoutesNet(new Stradario());

    loadStrade(m.getRoutesNet());  // why loadStrade must be static :-(

}

public Stradario getRoutesNet() {
    return routesNet;
}

public void setRoutesNet(Stradario routesNet) {
    this.routesNet = routesNet;
}

public void loadStrade(Stradario str) {
    // some code to fill routesNet

}
```

Comment: You are calling the method from a static context (the static method `main`). Either make the method `static` , or call the method on an instance of `GestioneStrade`, e.g `m.loadStrade(m.getRoutesNet());`

Comment: Is this class a `nested` class?

Comment: Note: it's not telling you to change `public void` to `public static`, it will be to `public static void`: you still need a return type.

Comment: See [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context).

Comment: is your method enclosed inside class?

Answer (score 1):

In "main" you should replace

```
loadStrade(m.getRoutesNet());
```

to

```
m.loadStrade(m.getRoutesNet());
```

And leave loadStrade as non-static.

Comment: Or(/and) change `loadStrade` so that it doesn't take the parameter at all, and have it call its own `getRoutesNet()` method.

Comment: Thaks you very much, now is clear to me. As a java  beginner,  things like this,  take me lot of time to be solved.